# How to make booking ID by PHP with MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have case like this:

```
JS100829 0001
JS100829 0002

JS=code
10=year
08=month
29=date
0001=the sequence of today first entry
0002=the sequence of today second entry
```

I need generate this code. Anyone can help me?
thanks.

Comment: Where exactly do you face the problem? I can tell you to `echo $code,$year,$month,$date,' ',$sequence;` but i think thats not what you want to hear

Comment: how to make sequence id?
so It auto increment system by current date

Comment: JS is always same, the confusing me is how to generate auto increment of sequence that begin of each day?
so if the day has change, it will be return by 0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you have a database for these booking entries, this is my best guess:

```
//sequences
$datenow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//i suppose u has load mysql db somewhere before this code
$q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtablename WHERE bookingdate = '$datenow'");
//how many squences today
$sequencedtoday = mysql_result($q, 0, 0);
//generate code:
$code = 'JS';
$ymd = date('ymd');
$squence = $squencedtoday+1;
$squence = str_pad($squence,4,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
//return
echo $code.$ymd.' '.$squence;
//return: JS100829 0001
```

Comment: Do not use mysql_num_rows() for counting rows! This is MySQL's COUNT() job.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using the MyISAM or the BDB engine you can create a complex auto_increment sequence.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html says:

> For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as
>
> ```
>  MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix.
> ```
>
> This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

demo:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$pdo->exec('
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soTest (
    `code` char(2),
    `date` DATE,
    `seq` int auto_increment,
    primary key(`date`, `seq`)
  ) engine=MyISAM
');
insertTestdata($pdo);
showData($pdo);

function insertTestdata($pdo) {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO soTest (`code`,`date`) VALUES (?,?)');
  $rs = array(
    array('JS', '2010-08-29'), array('JS', '2010-08-29'), array('TA', '2010-08-29'),
    array('JS', '2010-08-30'), array('TA', '2010-08-31'), array('TA', '2010-08-31')
  );
  foreach($rs as $r ) {
    $stmt->execute($r);
  }
}

function showData($pdo) {
  $query = "SELECT code,Date_format(`date`, '%y%m%d') as dt, seq FROM soTest";
  foreach( $pdo->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
    printf("%s%s %04d\n", $row['code'],$row['dt'],$row['seq']);
  }
}
```

prints

```
JS100829 0001
JS100829 0002
TA100829 0003
JS100830 0001
TA100831 0001
TA100831 0002
```

Keep in mind:

> When an AUTO_INCREMENT column is defined as the last column of a multiple-column index, reuse of values deleted from the top of a sequence does occur.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing where the "sequence counter" is maintained, this is my best shot (verbosity on purpose):

```
$code = 'JS';
$date = date('ymd');
$seq  = 1;
$id = sprintf('%s%s %04d', $code, $date, $seq);
```

Comment: Hmm, probably not what you're looking for, cf. comment on question.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the value of `$sequence` in database or a config file. Keep incrementing it everytime an ID is generated. A database table with columns:

- Date: date  ( also primary key)
- LatestID:  int

Then, do something like this:

```
$sequence = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select LatestID from seqtable where Date = CURDATE()"));
$sequence = $sequence + 1;

$code = "JS";
$mycode = $code . date("ymd") . str_pad($sequence, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

mysql_query("insert into seqtable set LatestID = $sequence, Date = CURDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LatestID = $sequence");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
    JS=code
    10=year
    08=month
    29=date
    0001=the sequence of today first entry
    0002=the sequence of today second entry
    */
    $js="JS";
    $date=date('ymd');
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    {
      $entry=str_pad($i,4,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
      echo $js.$date.$entry."<br>";
    }
//output
/*
JS1008290001
JS1008290002
JS1008290003
JS1008290004
JS1008290005
JS1008290006
JS1008290007
JS1008290008
JS1008290009
JS1008290010
*/
```